# ActiveRecord: Filter record by nested record attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

In my Rails application I have 2 models: Students and Courses.

Students have many courses.

Running the command Student.first.courses into the rails console would result in a collection of the courses belonging to the first student being returned.

What I'm wondering is if it's possible to write a command that would check if there were any students with a particular course.

For example if I wanted to see if there were any students with 'English' as one of their courses, how would I write this?

Any help would be much appreciated - thanks!

Comment: And Course belong to Student? This way, you will have many instances of the same course (once for every Student), you might want to revisit your design and have it so, Student _has and belongs to many_ (or _has many through_, read the documentation for both), so that you have a single instance of "English" shared across students.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep, that's absolutely possible:

```
Student.joins(:courses).where(courses: { name: 'English' })
```

See [the docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) for more info on the topic.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks, I'll check out the docs you've linked and accept your answer once the timer expires.

Answer (score 1):

Following on from Andrey's answer, you can wrap that up in a scope within your Student model, like this:

```
scope :taking, ->(subject_name) { joins(:courses).where(courses: {name: subject_name})}
```

and then use it with:

```
Student.taking("English")
```